# cannot install NuGet package into project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I cannot install the NuGet package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (.Net JWT Handler) into my project.  If i try to install the package with NuGet, it will install into the root of the solution only (a .nuget folder is created in the root of the solution).  I need to install the package in my project, not the solution.

Why would this happen?  I tried passing in the project name to the Install-Package command in the Package Manager Console, and that looks like it installs correctly but no references are added to my project and the packages.config file is not updated.

My project is currently referencing .Net 4.5.1 and I have also tried with .Net 4.5.

The package I am trying to install is here:
[System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I was trying to install the package as said in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205064(v=vs.110).aspx 
So, I look into the package history and finally I installed the previous package 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/3.0.0

It works fine for me.

Comment: Brilliant!  This worked...  I wonder why they added the new feature of not being able to install the package?

Comment: BTW if anyone is wondering, the command to install the ealier version is this:  Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Version 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

With NuGet, you can now specify the directory the packages are installed in.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1

**Specify ‘packages’ Folder Location**

In the past, NuGet has managed a solution’s packages from a known ‘packages’ folder found beneath the solution root directory. For development teams that have many different solutions which have NuGet packages installed, this can result in the same package being installed in many different places on the file system. NuGet 2.1 provides more granular control over the location of the packages folder via the ‘repositoryPath’ element in the NuGet.config file. Building on the previous example of hierarchical nuget.config support, assume that we wish to have all projects under C:\myteam\ share the same packages folder. To accomplish this, simply add the following entry to C:\myteam\nuget.config.

Comment: The problem is, the package will not install into my project.  My solution has 3 different projects in it, and instead of installing into the selected project, the package is installed into the root of the solution (both on the disk, and in solution explorer).  I have tried specifying the project I want the package intalled in, but that had no effect...

Answer (score 0):

The package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 3.0.1 has some problems: the file `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.Xml` should be put in directory `lib\net45`, but they are put in the root directory instead. This causes NuGet to think the package is a solution level package, and will not install the package into a project.

This problem was fixed in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 3.0.2